# Understanding a calibration plot for lightGBM binary classifier

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, boosting, calibration

I wanted to assess the performance of my lightGBM classifier using a calibration plot. If I understood correctly, a calibration plot visualizes the alignment between the predicted probabilities by the model and the observed outcomes in the data. In a good model I would ideally see the three lines overlaying each other.

Based on the plot I obtained, it seems that my model is performing well. However, I'm unclear about the purpose and interpretation of the confidence band in the graph. While I initially assumed it would provide a confidence range around the Bias-corrected line, its significance in this plot remains ambiguous to me. Can someone please provide clarity on this?

[image]

Comment: I do not see a confidence band on the plot. I see a black line, a green curve, a blue curve, and some kind of plot of the predicted probability values. Could you please re-plot with the band?

Comment: If you zoom in very closely, there is a band on the bottom of the plot. This seems very strange, how did you produce this plot?

Comment: How was this created? A confidence interval on a probability estimate is always a bit iffy as a notion. I haven't seen calibration plots with confidence intervals often, can you please link the resource you followed?